# Is it possible to reload the router in a running ember.js app in order to update the path strings of routes?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, routes

I'm implementing multi-language support in my app, and I guess this is the last thing that I would need in order to be able to change between languages without reloading the whole app/page. (I already have a solution  with full page reload.)

For a simple example let's say this is how my router looks:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('search', { path: t('search') });
  this.route('item', { path: `${t('item')}/:id`);
});
```

The `t` function would be getting the correct translation for the given strings in the currently active language.

The structure of the route hierarchy won't change, the only things that need to be updated are the path strings. Application state should be kept, of course.

I'm wondering whether this is possible to do.

Answer (score 1):

I am not %100 sure about the correctness of what I wrote but `Router.map` is executed and resources with the definitions given within this method is transformed to a [DSL](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.12.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/dsl.js) instance and that is then passed to the actual [router](https://github.com/tildeio/router.js/) maintained by [Ember.Router](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.12.0/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/router.js) itself. In order to achieve what you want I believe what we need is dynamic modification to the router even if it is just the paths you need yo modify not the whole route structure.

If you look at the following [github issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/10979), Ember.js no more supports dynamically adding routes (hence no dynamic modification to the existing ones I believe). With all that said, I believe what you want is not possible without reloading the whole app (hence losing the application state).